# hardware requirement for OpenGL

Tags: opengl

My knowledge of OpenGL is very little. I was researching on some RTOS for my project. Some sort of light wt. UI is also required. I came across the OpenGL support for some UI package. My doubt is that whether a separate GPU is required for OpenGL or not?

Answer (score 4):

No separate GPU is required, all you need are openGL drivers. There are even openGL software drivers (Mesa) that will render OpenGL onto anything.

Assuming it's a relatively recent RTOS it may support OpenGL-ES which is a reduced subset to support low power/low memory devices.